# How to move Svg icons?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create simple Rock, paper scissor game,  i have painted design of my game, 
[image]

Also, i have svg icons, i am trying to insert my icons on the top of triangle angle, like in picture below, 
my code is look like this:

```html
<div class="Triangle">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="305" height="277"><path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="15" d="M291.5 7.5H4.574c3.119 0 52.416 84.667 147.892 254L291.5 7.5z" opacity=".2"/></svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="49" height="59"><path fill="#3B4262" d="M47.125 11.832a2.922 2.922 0 00-1.232-.198c-.57.04-1.029.271-1.302.65-1.604 2.248-2.919 6.493-3.979 9.905-.486 1.577-1.14 3.688-1.612 4.69-.493-2.807.064-13.09.28-17.05l.003-.064c.15-2.751.17-3.234.138-3.446-.238-1.509-.843-2.5-1.799-2.943-.966-.45-2.22-.25-3.572.563-.677.41-.865 1.816-1.446 8.19l-.002.028c-.32 3.502-1.058 11.566-1.965 12.91-1.023-1.88-2.431-12.555-3.039-17.176-.425-3.236-.673-5.094-.84-5.655-.35-1.176-1.83-2.176-3.295-2.232-1.22-.06-2.22.56-2.698 1.638-.894.995-.578 4.292.41 12.102.47 3.718 1.44 11.395.83 12.257-1.219-.133-3.31-4.942-6.215-14.299-.816-2.62-1.068-3.408-1.318-3.753-.494-1.202-2.172-2.129-3.676-2.024a3.183 3.183 0 00-.377.049c-.787.156-2.584.881-2.2 4.226 1.06 4.637 2.213 8.041 3.331 11.346l.023.066c.669 1.98 1.302 3.85 1.89 5.925 1.385 4.9.846 7.94.84 7.975-.046.312-.143.503-.288.57a.556.556 0 01-.195.045c-.44.03-1.098-.26-1.437-.45-.776-1.482-4.636-8.544-8.134-9.524l-.126-.037-.127.012c-1.283.121-2.226.606-2.803 1.441-.914 1.32-.535 3.002-.444 3.34l.052.12c.028.051 2.834 5.165 3.268 7.544.374 2.04 2.311 4.25 3.869 6.026l.064.073c.508.58.946 1.083 1.292 1.548 4.519 4.713 11.665 8.677 11.723 8.71.892.657 1.387 1.293 1.44 1.84a.798.798 0 01-.16.58l-.155.162.988.96 18.853-1.324.804-3.684c2.486-10.402 1.967-19.272 1.958-19.33.01-.327.706-3.483 1.266-6.033l.017-.065c1.117-5.08 2.505-11.4 2.772-13.803.116-1.028-.542-1.972-1.675-2.401z"/></svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="51" height="58"><path fill="#3B4262" d="M13.971 25.702l6.012-8.415c-2.499-.415-7.088-.507-10.846 3.235C3.212 26.421.812 39.163.312 42.248L15.37 57.24c2.711-.232 14.713-1.827 26.279-13.34.122-.249 2.94-2.321.636-4.614-1.1-1.095-2.919-1.074-4.042.044-.572.57-1.461.577-2.021.02-.56-.557-.552-1.443.02-2.012l4.087-4.069c2.076-2.067.119-5.555-2.78-4.717l-3.345 2.851c-.611.53-1.52.439-2.022-.14-.519-.597-.408-1.503.183-2.013 11.687-10.208 9.98-8.979 17.5-15.995 2.809-2.329-.725-6.447-3.493-4.09L28.182 25.45c-.529.448-1.34.457-1.86-.02-.601-.517-.615-1.262-.222-1.85L38.787 3.944c1.854-2.5-1.795-5.277-3.749-2.757L16.28 27.307c-.452.65-1.364.8-1.985.345a1.377 1.377 0 01-.323-1.95z"/></svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48"><path fill="#3B4262" d="M45.06 12.22c-.642-8.096-9.734-7.269-9.734-7.269-3.837-6.765-9.832-1.865-9.832-1.865-4.606-6.63-10.38-.486-10.38-.486-9.957-1.074-9.571 7.066-9.571 7.066-.234 2.588 1.403 10.593 1.403 10.593-1.477-4.614-4.68-.784-4.68-.784-3.94 6.078-.975 9.405-.975 9.405 5.33 6.246 16.688 13.743 16.688 13.743 4.113 2.356 2.373 4.457 2.373 4.457l24.876-4.11.571-4.718c3.782-11.436-.739-26.032-.739-26.032z"/></svg>
</div>
```

I tryed a lot but still can't solve this: for example this not works for all devices

```html
<div class="Triangle">
  
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="305" height="277"><path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="15" d="M291.5 7.5H4.574c3.119 0 52.416 84.667 147.892 254L291.5 7.5z" opacity=".2"/></svg>

<span class="tran1" style="position: relative; right: 183px;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="49" height="59"><path fill="#3B4262" d="M47.125 11.832a2.922 2.922 0 00-1.232-.198c-.57.04-1.029.271-1.302.65-1.604 2.248-2.919 6.493-3.979 9.905-.486 1.577-1.14 3.688-1.612 4.69-.493-2.807.064-13.09.28-17.05l.003-.064c.15-2.751.17-3.234.138-3.446-.238-1.509-.843-2.5-1.799-2.943-.966-.45-2.22-.25-3.572.563-.677.41-.865 1.816-1.446 8.19l-.002.028c-.32 3.502-1.058 11.566-1.965 12.91-1.023-1.88-2.431-12.555-3.039-17.176-.425-3.236-.673-5.094-.84-5.655-.35-1.176-1.83-2.176-3.295-2.232-1.22-.06-2.22.56-2.698 1.638-.894.995-.578 4.292.41 12.102.47 3.718 1.44 11.395.83 12.257-1.219-.133-3.31-4.942-6.215-14.299-.816-2.62-1.068-3.408-1.318-3.753-.494-1.202-2.172-2.129-3.676-2.024a3.183 3.183 0 00-.377.049c-.787.156-2.584.881-2.2 4.226 1.06 4.637 2.213 8.041 3.331 11.346l.023.066c.669 1.98 1.302 3.85 1.89 5.925 1.385 4.9.846 7.94.84 7.975-.046.312-.143.503-.288.57a.556.556 0 01-.195.045c-.44.03-1.098-.26-1.437-.45-.776-1.482-4.636-8.544-8.134-9.524l-.126-.037-.127.012c-1.283.121-2.226.606-2.803 1.441-.914 1.32-.535 3.002-.444 3.34l.052.12c.028.051 2.834 5.165 3.268 7.544.374 2.04 2.311 4.25 3.869 6.026l.064.073c.508.58.946 1.083 1.292 1.548 4.519 4.713 11.665 8.677 11.723 8.71.892.657 1.387 1.293 1.44 1.84a.798.798 0 01-.16.58l-.155.162.988.96 18.853-1.324.804-3.684c2.486-10.402 1.967-19.272 1.958-19.33.01-.327.706-3.483 1.266-6.033l.017-.065c1.117-5.08 2.505-11.4 2.772-13.803.116-1.028-.542-1.972-1.675-2.401z"/></svg>
</span>
  <span class="tran2" style="position: relative; bottom: 260px; right: 90px;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="51" height="58"><path fill="#3B4262" d="M13.971 25.702l6.012-8.415c-2.499-.415-7.088-.507-10.846 3.235C3.212 26.421.812 39.163.312 42.248L15.37 57.24c2.711-.232 14.713-1.827 26.279-13.34.122-.249 2.94-2.321.636-4.614-1.1-1.095-2.919-1.074-4.042.044-.572.57-1.461.577-2.021.02-.56-.557-.552-1.443.02-2.012l4.087-4.069c2.076-2.067.119-5.555-2.78-4.717l-3.345 2.851c-.611.53-1.52.439-2.022-.14-.519-.597-.408-1.503.183-2.013 11.687-10.208 9.98-8.979 17.5-15.995 2.809-2.329-.725-6.447-3.493-4.09L28.182 25.45c-.529.448-1.34.457-1.86-.02-.601-.517-.615-1.262-.222-1.85L38.787 3.944c1.854-2.5-1.795-5.277-3.749-2.757L16.28 27.307c-.452.65-1.364.8-1.985.345a1.377 1.377 0 01-.323-1.95z"/></svg>
  </span>
<span class="tran3" style="position: relative; right: 440px; bottom: 260px;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48"><path fill="#3B4262" d="M45.06 12.22c-.642-8.096-9.734-7.269-9.734-7.269-3.837-6.765-9.832-1.865-9.832-1.865-4.606-6.63-10.38-.486-10.38-.486-9.957-1.074-9.571 7.066-9.571 7.066-.234 2.588 1.403 10.593 1.403 10.593-1.477-4.614-4.68-.784-4.68-.784-3.94 6.078-.975 9.405-.975 9.405 5.33 6.246 16.688 13.743 16.688 13.743 4.113 2.356 2.373 4.457 2.373 4.457l24.876-4.11.571-4.718c3.782-11.436-.739-26.032-.739-26.032z"/></svg>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

1. I would transform the hands from svg to symbol and put them in the same svg element as the triangle. Also I would remove the width and height attributes and use a viewBox attribute instead. Although this is not very important I would take care that the 3 symbols have the same aspect ratio, i.e square. Also is important to give the symbols a `id` since I would use them with `use`
2. For the triangle I would recalculate the wiewBox allowing some extra space for the hands. Please observe that I've changed the d attribute of the triangle since you were using a bezier for one of sides and the triangle didn't close well.
3. I'm using the symbols with use. Since the symbols have a wiewBox I can give the use element a position (x,y) a width and a height. I'm placing the symbols on the triangle and I'm making the use elements width="45" height="45". You can use a different size.

```html
<div class="Triangle">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-50 -50 400 350" >

  <symbol id="a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-5 0 59 59" ><path fill="#3B4262" d="M47.125 11.832a2.922 2.922 0 00-1.232-.198c-.57.04-1.029.271-1.302.65-1.604 2.248-2.919 6.493-3.979 9.905-.486 1.577-1.14 3.688-1.612 4.69-.493-2.807.064-13.09.28-17.05l.003-.064c.15-2.751.17-3.234.138-3.446-.238-1.509-.843-2.5-1.799-2.943-.966-.45-2.22-.25-3.572.563-.677.41-.865 1.816-1.446 8.19l-.002.028c-.32 3.502-1.058 11.566-1.965 12.91-1.023-1.88-2.431-12.555-3.039-17.176-.425-3.236-.673-5.094-.84-5.655-.35-1.176-1.83-2.176-3.295-2.232-1.22-.06-2.22.56-2.698 1.638-.894.995-.578 4.292.41 12.102.47 3.718 1.44 11.395.83 12.257-1.219-.133-3.31-4.942-6.215-14.299-.816-2.62-1.068-3.408-1.318-3.753-.494-1.202-2.172-2.129-3.676-2.024a3.183 3.183 0 00-.377.049c-.787.156-2.584.881-2.2 4.226 1.06 4.637 2.213 8.041 3.331 11.346l.023.066c.669 1.98 1.302 3.85 1.89 5.925 1.385 4.9.846 7.94.84 7.975-.046.312-.143.503-.288.57a.556.556 0 01-.195.045c-.44.03-1.098-.26-1.437-.45-.776-1.482-4.636-8.544-8.134-9.524l-.126-.037-.127.012c-1.283.121-2.226.606-2.803 1.441-.914 1.32-.535 3.002-.444 3.34l.052.12c.028.051 2.834 5.165 3.268 7.544.374 2.04 2.311 4.25 3.869 6.026l.064.073c.508.58.946 1.083 1.292 1.548 4.519 4.713 11.665 8.677 11.723 8.71.892.657 1.387 1.293 1.44 1.84a.798.798 0 01-.16.58l-.155.162.988.96 18.853-1.324.804-3.684c2.486-10.402 1.967-19.272 1.958-19.33.01-.327.706-3.483 1.266-6.033l.017-.065c1.117-5.08 2.505-11.4 2.772-13.803.116-1.028-.542-1.972-1.675-2.401z"/></symbol>
  <symbol id="b" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-3.5 0 58 58" ><path fill="#3B4262" d="M13.971 25.702l6.012-8.415c-2.499-.415-7.088-.507-10.846 3.235C3.212 26.421.812 39.163.312 42.248L15.37 57.24c2.711-.232 14.713-1.827 26.279-13.34.122-.249 2.94-2.321.636-4.614-1.1-1.095-2.919-1.074-4.042.044-.572.57-1.461.577-2.021.02-.56-.557-.552-1.443.02-2.012l4.087-4.069c2.076-2.067.119-5.555-2.78-4.717l-3.345 2.851c-.611.53-1.52.439-2.022-.14-.519-.597-.408-1.503.183-2.013 11.687-10.208 9.98-8.979 17.5-15.995 2.809-2.329-.725-6.447-3.493-4.09L28.182 25.45c-.529.448-1.34.457-1.86-.02-.601-.517-.615-1.262-.222-1.85L38.787 3.944c1.854-2.5-1.795-5.277-3.749-2.757L16.28 27.307c-.452.65-1.364.8-1.985.345a1.377 1.377 0 01-.323-1.95z"/></symbol>
  <symbol id="c" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48 48" ><path fill="#3B4262" d="M45.06 12.22c-.642-8.096-9.734-7.269-9.734-7.269-3.837-6.765-9.832-1.865-9.832-1.865-4.606-6.63-10.38-.486-10.38-.486-9.957-1.074-9.571 7.066-9.571 7.066-.234 2.588 1.403 10.593 1.403 10.593-1.477-4.614-4.68-.784-4.68-.784-3.94 6.078-.975 9.405-.975 9.405 5.33 6.246 16.688 13.743 16.688 13.743 4.113 2.356 2.373 4.457 2.373 4.457l24.876-4.11.571-4.718c3.782-11.436-.739-26.032-.739-26.032z"/></symbol>
    
        
    
    <path id="t" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="15" d="M291.5 7.5H4.574L147.892 254L291.5 7.5z" opacity=".2"/>
    
    
    <use xlink:href="#a" width="45" height="45" x="-22" y="-22"/>
    <use xlink:href="#b" width="45" height="45" x="270" y="-22"/>
    <use xlink:href="#c" width="45" height="45" x="125" y="232"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```